# how do i get time (hh:mm:ss) from given string?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I am getting a string from web service in this format, pubDate:"Fri, 19 Jul 2013 07:13:44 GMT"
I want to print just the time in HH:mm:ss format,i.e, I want to print 07:13:44.
How I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried on google ?

Comment: Two choices:  regular expression or `NSDateFormatter`

Comment: I tried on google, but I am totally confused. Any help with an example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
NSString *str = @"Fri, 19 Jul 2013 07:13:44 GMT";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:str];
NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[df setTimeZone:sourceTimeZone];

NSDate *dateFromString = [df dateFromString:str];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

// This is the time you need
NSString *timeIs = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: This is not quite right.  First of all there is no AM/PM information, so you should use `HH` instead of `hh` and second of all it will display in the user's local timezone (so for example, here in Japan, `time` will be 04:13:44 for `hh` and 16:13:44 for `HH`

Comment: @borrrden I have edited my answer according to timezone.

Comment: Heh, and now both of the answers are (almost) exactly the same.  Except that you didn't make your second format 'HH' as well (which is not explicitly a requirement from the given information, so I'll +1 you anyway)

Comment: I have updated. anyways thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

NSString *pubDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fri, 19 Jul 2013 07:13:44 GMT"];

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];

NSDate *pubDate = [df dateFromString:pubDateString];

[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

NSLog(@"%@",[df stringFromDate:pubDate]);
```

Output: `07:13:44`

Apple's Date Formatting Guide:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: This does not answer the question.  -1

Comment: Apologies, had just realized that. Already edited my answer.

Comment: Almost, but OP wants to output 07:13:44, not 15:13:44.  I removed my downvote though.

Comment: Oops, you're right. Forgot to set the timezone. Edited.

Comment: Alright, now you get a +1 for your effort ^^